# Objective-c DenseMap error

Tags: objective-c, debugging

I would like to know why it's happening, sometime in my domino game, at time to put domino at table this error is showed, sorry for my bad english. I'm looking for someting that help me to solve this, is only thing that i need to publish my app.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with allocation issues, or even `denseMap()` (which is actually a pretty cool function of the internals of [NSObject's allocation mechanism](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm)).  When the runtime detects that your application is recursing, it terminates the process.  `-[GameViewController playGame]` appears to be calling itself from within itself.

Comment: exactly, this also happens when a view is added as a subview of itself, (or a layer), or any other mistake that causes recursion.